# Is <iostream> needed to use a string in c++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, string, iostream

This code works for me:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string s;
    s = "hello world";
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

But this one doesn't:

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
    string s;
    s = "hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

Is the include of `<iostream>` needed as well as the `<string>` one?

I'm using Eclipse CDT IDE.

Comment: You need the `std::` before `string`, not `<iostream>`. Though I'm quite doubtful that the first one actually compiled since it should be complaining about the missing `std::` before `cout`.

Comment: std::string... I could not figure out why you remember it in your first example but forget it in the second one.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. Didn't expect the same namespace being used in two different "libraries" at the same time. The cout thing is because i copy pasted the code and modified it to look like mine, but missed that std.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iostream is not needed to use string. You are missing using namespace std (or alternatively using the std:: prefix) in the second example, that's why it's not working.

Comment: I'm seriously tempted to downvote this for suggesting the using namespace std monstrosity.